# "Compress" option disappears from right click menu when I search for a file on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: nautilus, archive, compression, zip

I'm searching through a folder to compress a file for sending, and I've noticed that if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type the file name, or just begin typing the file name, then the option to 'Compress...' the file disappears from my  right click menu. If I scroll through the list of files, this option is still there.

Any ideas on why it's disappearing after the search, or what I can do? Otherwise I'm going to be spending a lot of time scrolling.

Comment: I guess you are using the search function so you have the focus on the file without the need to scroll down. But in Nautilus this also searches through all the subdirectories. If you don't need that, you could use a different file manager. For example Thunar provides the same feature (you can just type and it jumps to the first file in the viewed folder starting with the string) and you then can compress or archive that file.

Comment: You'll also need the package `thunar-archive-plugin`.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer, without changing from the default file manager.

- Search from the "Home" folder
- Right click on the item
- Select "Open item location"
- Right click on the item, and "Compress" is now an option

Item is now found within the folder, and can compress it so problem solved. However if anyone has any ideas why searching through the subdirectories caused this problem, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Wow, this workaround works.